# How to make a Dual Boot UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, kali

I want to make a dual boot with Kali or BlackArch with Zorin or Bodhi, but the biggest problem is the UEFI, they don't detect the other or dont boot. So, how can i do a dual-boot in this situation?

Comment: are they all installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: Sometimes they run with the UEFI ON, Bodhi only run on UEFI and i dunno why, Kali and Zorin run with UEFI ON/OFF, and BlackArch don't work at all, rarely run(just on UEFI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install one distribution of your choice (e.g. Kali Linux) in order to install basic files, GRUB etc.

Then, install the other distribution of your choice (e.g. Zorin).

It maybe boot Kali Linux only. If it does, let Kali start up. Then, open a terminal window, and run`sudo update-grub` in order to make GRUB notice that there is another OS.

If it does not boot Kali only and displays you a screen like the one below, leave GRUB intact. **Do not execute the command above in neither of the two OSes.**

[image: GRUB 2 Boot Manager from Ubuntu 16.04]

Make sure to modify the UEFI settings in your motherboard in order to boot the OSes.

Hope this works!

Comment: I'll try, not now, because i need to save some archives on cloud, hope this solve my problem.. and thx bro..

Comment: @RickyMatheus You're welcome! :)

Comment: Somehow the dual works, that was hard, 2 days for them to identify each other, in the end i got the problem with just one booting and the code you gave me was helpfull, thx bro....

Comment: @RickyMatheus You're welcome! But did GRUB recognize both OSes?